# Is this the right way to create a console application?

Tags: c++, optimization, console-application

I'm trying to create a console application using C++. The application is intended to be used as a "calculator" for string-rewriting systems, and will function as stand-alone executable with, at most, the option to read from and write to files created by the user (nothing fancy, just the console and a short list of commands).

I haven't finished the code yet, but the overall format looks like this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include //...other #includes

using namespace std;

//...class declarations

//...function declarations

void input_parser(string input)
{
    while (input != "exit")
    {
        cin >> input;
        //...function body (switch (input) or if (input))
            {return output;}
        cout << output << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    input_parser(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I've been using C++ for about two weeks now, and this is my first time writing an application. I don't know if there's a better way to go about it, but I'm worried that running everything through `input_parser` take more time than some other method, especially since the process of identifying commands can take some doing.

(For example, in order to input the rewrite rule `((a -> b) and (b -> c)) -> (a -> c)` - that is, "replace an occurrence of the substring '(a -> b) and (b -> c)' with the string '(a -> c)'" - the program needs to be able to distinguish between the central occurrence of `->`, which indicates the rule, and the other three, which are part of the initial and replacement strings. So far, the fastest way I've been able to do this is by counting parentheses.)

Comment: `int main();{ /*...*/ }` is wrong due to the `;`

Comment: @crashmstr that was a typo. My focus is on whether or not reading the input and selecting an appropriate command is the right way to go about this.

Comment: Don't worry too much about performance before meassuring it. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Focus on clean, readable and working code. You probably want to read a whole line with `std::getline(std::cin, input);` instead of only a single word. Then you can parse this line. But writing a parser is quite a big topic.

Comment: This is not the right way. There is no point in passing an empty string into a function to then make a copy of it and keep on overwriting it.

Comment: @rustyx What would the correct way be?